# Difference between Probability Distributions Chi^2 and F (with applications)

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

My question is, is there anybody that can explain and dumb down the differences of the two different distributions (Chi-squared and F). I have tried doing research on the internet but I can't seem to understand what is being conveyed.
Basically what is the difference in Chi-Squared and F and how are they used in industry.

Now I know that this question is not super clear but I am just trying to gather as much information from experts on here so that I can advance my statistical knowledge.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Grab a textbook. Your question is too broad to be covered in one question on this website. Learn some probability with calculus, and then grab a statistics-with-calculus textbook. I recommend Wackerly's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications* (this covers both prob and stats). This is not one of those things that you can just have someone tell you and you'll just magically learn it. It will take a lot of work. I recommend that you go through that whole textbook.

Comment: Yes you are correct and I will be looking to read this book quite soon. Thank you!

Comment: Also (maybe this goes unsaid), make sure you're really good with calculus (derivatives, integrals, partial derivatives, double integrals) and summation notation before reading that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F distribution is the distribution of the ratio of two $\chi^2$ distribution variables, as shown in [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Characterization). They're both widely used by practitioners. Look up [$\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) and [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) in Google.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a quick case study or example of how they are used? any real data? That does help though ^

Comment: Search our site, Alex: illustrations of $\chi^2$ tests appear in hundreds, if not thousands, of answers.  The $F$ test is illustrated much more rarely but it is frequently mentioned, so there may be a few worked examples.

Comment: You're right, ill start looking on here first. Then if I have another question I will try to ask it in more detail!